# Google Map marker coordinate string to number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, google-maps, numbers

I am trying to create a Google Map with a single coordinate as marker. I use ASP MVC, and the coordinates are saved in the database as a string.

```
<%: Model.LatLng %>
```

outputs something like this:  52.425, 4.938

The problem is, Google Maps cannot read this, probably because it is a string. How do I convert the coordinates to something Google Maps can read?

Google map code (just default example)

```
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng, 
  map: map, 
  title:"Hello World!"
});
```

mylatlng needs to be <%: Model.LatLng %> but since its a string it won't work.

Comment: You're using the Google Maps API? ... Can you show us how you're rendering the map?

Comment: Yes sorry, I am using Api v3. Currently just using a example from the api documentation. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the anwser:

```
var LatLng = "<%: Model.LatLng %>";

    var latlngparts = LatLng.split(",");
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlngparts[0]), parseFloat(latlngparts[1]));
```